# Removing iOS original apps

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

As the title says, I'm looking at apps I've moved to the second screen, and wondering if I can remove these. These are the iOS apps that came with a fresh install, so no simple delete option. It would help free up some memory, as I'd never use these.

(for what it's worth, it will be a business phone, used only for the business. I have my regular iPhone with all the apps I want.)

Answer (score 2):

You would need to download [Apple Configurator](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12), then configure a profile, connect your device and install this profile, restart phone. I'm sure there will be tutorials how to do this, if you struggle, just reply here. :)

Answer (score -1):

Lots of hoops to jump through to really delete them, or to hide them with Tap Hide Apps (as they reappear when you reboot, as one does with an iOS update.)

I just pulled them all into a folder and labeled it AppleCrapApps.

Comment: I can hide them on a second page. My goal is to remove completely. And no, I did not DV you.

Comment: Me neither, but I UV'ed :P